# Unable To Download Software VIA Terminal

Tags: command-line, repository, downloads, wget

Trying to Download repos but this error shows up, this happens always while trying to download any other repositories also.

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/osmoma/audio-recorder/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.Reading package lists... Done
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/osmoma/audio-recorder/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/osmoma/audio-recorder/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/osmoma/audio-recorder/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  503  Service Unavailable
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: The example PPA (osmoma) simply does not have a Xenial version. Nothing to download.  PPAs can be browsed with any web browser - look for yourself.